# Copy constructor understanding

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I was going through [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_copy_constructor.htm) to study copy constructor again.

**CODE:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Line
{
   public:
      int getLength( void );
      Line( int len );             // simple constructor
      Line( const Line &obj);  // copy constructor
      ~Line();                     // destructor

   private:
      int *ptr;
};

// Member functions definitions including constructor
Line::Line(int len)
{
    cout << "Normal constructor allocating ptr" << endl;
    // allocate memory for the pointer;
    ptr = new int;
    *ptr = len;
}

Line::Line(const Line &obj)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor allocating ptr." << endl;
    ptr = new int;
   *ptr = *obj.ptr; // copy the value
}

Line::~Line(void)
{
    cout << "Freeing memory!" << endl;
    delete ptr;
}
int Line::getLength( void )
{
    return *ptr;
}

void display(Line obj)
{
   cout << "Length of line : " << obj.getLength() <<endl;
}

// Main function for the program
int main( )
{
   Line line(10);

   display(line);

   return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Normal constructor allocating ptr
Copy constructor allocating ptr.
Length of line : 10
Freeing memory!
Freeing memory!
```

I was wondering why it is calling Copy constructor in `Line line(10)`. I think it should call the normal constructor only. I'm not cloning any object here. Please someone explain me this.

Comment: display's obj is a copy of line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The copy constructor is called because the function parameter is passed by value. Here

```
void display(Line obj)
```

the function is defined as taking the `Line` parameter by value. This results in a copy of the argument being made. Had you passed by reference, the copy constructor would not be called

Answer (score 3):

> **I was wondering why it is calling Copy constructor in `Line line(10)`.**

No, it does not.
It just calls the constructor for `Line` class constructor which takes a `int` as parameter.

---

```
void display(Line obj)
```

Passes `Line` object ***by value*** and hence copy constructor is called to create the copy being passed to the function.

In C++ function arguments are passsed by value by default. And the copy of these objects is created by calling the copy constructor of that class.